# Why JavaFX PrintJob cannot print node's text properly?

Tags: javafx, printing

I try to print a javafx scene with texts on it. I have created this very simple test code. As you can see it's a standard hello world application with a button that says "Say Hello World.

The application supposes to print out this scene with the button that shows "Say 'Hello World'". The program prints out the form fine. However, the texts on the button are shown as unrecognizable characters instead. I use Mac.

I am trying to implement a javafx report, and it requires to print out a javafx scene.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you can successfully print the characters. Therefore, at least, I know it's my printer's problem.

To make the test easy, you can save the result as a pdf file instead of printing it out.

```
package javafxprinttest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.print.PrinterJob;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class JavaFXPrintTest extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");


    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
            print(root);
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

private void print(Node node) 
{
    // Define the Job Status Message
            System.out.println("Creating a printer job...");
    // Create a printer job for the default printer
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();

    if (job != null && job.showPrintDialog(node.getScene().getWindow())) 
    {
        // Print the node
        boolean printed = job.printPage(node);

        if (printed) 
        {
            // End the printer job
            job.endJob();
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Write Error Message
                            System.out.println("Printing failed.");
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Write Error Message
                    System.out.println("Could not create a printer job.");
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the font that displays on a screen may not be the same font that an OS recognizes it. Therefore, when you try to print or save the scene as pdf, random characters may be saved as result.

```
btn.setFont(new Font("Arial", 30));
```

The above code fixes the problem by providing a font that is known by the OS.

Notice that not everyone will be able to produce the same result. I have a friend of mine to run the same code on his box, and the result shows up fine.